# Flag column for when a different column value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2014.

I have a query that has a field named "sitecode".  I select the data and order it by sitecode.  I need a helper column that who's value changes from 1 to 0 whenever the sitecode changes.

As in:

```
Helper  SiteCode
1       A
1       A
1       A
0       B
1       C
1       C
0       D
0       D
```

Comment: This is needed to feed a "helper column" in Excel used for striped formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` to get a continuous number for each `sitecode` and calculate the modulo 2 to get your alternating 1s and 0s.

```
SELECT sitecode,
       dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY sitecode) % 2 helper
       FROM elbat;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0fcb3656b032928bf57743c49a0795b9)

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.  If you have one, then `lag()` does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(sitecode) over (order by ?) <> sitecode then 0 else 1 end) as flag
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't familiar with lag, I need to learn how to use it.  Appreciate the example.